# Match any substring from the beginning of a word

Tags: regex, perl

For example, with a line like `previous`, I want the pattern to match the lines `p`, `pr`, `pre`, `prev`, etc., all the way up to `previous`. I do NOT want it to match lines like `prevalent` or `previse`.
Is there a pattern to accomplish this aside from the obvious (`^(p|pr|pre|prev|...|previous)$`)?

Note: I do not need to capture it like in the above pattern, and
I'm using Perl's regular expression flavor (in Perl).

Comment: Not trying to be facetious or anything, but what's wrong with simply using `/previous/`?

Comment: @Manny it will not match on `p` and not on `pr` ...

Comment: Nothing, really. My script takes commands like `previous`, and I was wondering how I could implement this (but I probably won't). I'm simply curious.

Comment: [Text::Abbrev](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Text%3A%3AAbbrev&mode=all) may be a better solution than rolling your own regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think regex is the best (or most readable) way to do this:

```
$str = "previous";
$input = "prev";
$length = length($input);

$strcheck = substr($str, 0, $length);
$incheck = substr($input, 0, $length);

if ($strcheck =~ $incheck && $length != 0) {
    // do something with $input
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
/^p(r(e(v(i(o(u(s)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/
```

And just to double check that it works:

```
for (qw/p pr pre previous prevalent previse/) {
    $result = (/^p(r(e(v(i(o(u(s)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/? "yes" : "no");
    print "Checking $_: $result\n";
}
```

Produces:

```
Checking p: yes
Checking pr: yes
Checking pre: yes
Checking previous: yes
Checking prevalent: no
Checking previse: no
```

Comment: It will match: `revious`, `evious`, etc.

Comment: That gets ugly if you don't want the captures. But it is better than what @loliii had. `/^p(?:r(?:e(?:v(?:i(?:o(?:u(?:s)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$/`. oh, and you dropped the end anchor.

Comment: @polishchuk: No it won't. The "p" isn't optional. And the "r" isn't optional if you include the "e", etc...

Comment: @Adam, I mean that OP needs matches like: `p`, `pr`, `pre` and not `previous`, `revious`, `evious`...

Comment: @polishchuk: Actually it *should* match "previous". But to my knowledge, my RE does exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Adam, May be I misinterpret question, +1 anyway :-)

Comment: I knew how the regex would look, but seeing it actually written down makes me laugh :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "previous"; 
my @array = split //,$string;

chomp(my $input=<STDIN>); #take the input from the user
my @array2 = split //,$input;

my $i=0;

foreach (@array2){
        if($_ eq $array[$i]){
            print "$_ matched\n";
        }
$i++;
}
```