# Match word and any amount of first sequential characters of the word

Tags: regex

Is there a simpler way to write the following regular expression, specifically avoiding all the groupings with the '?' optional character?

```
/^w(o(r(d)?)?)?$/
```

It **should** match the following:

- w
- wo
- wor
- word

and **should not** match, as mere examples:

- wr
- wd
- woo
- wrr
- wodr
- wrdo
- ord
- rd
- odr

In this particular case its a very short word but you can see by this next example how things can become ugly very fast.

Regex to match *vertical* or *horizontal* and any amount of first sequential characters of each word:

```
/^h(o(r(i(z(o(n(t(a(l)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?|v(e(r(t(i(c(a(l)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)$/
```

I'm using ruby but I think this question applies to any language that makes use of regular expressions, so I'll thank answers in any language. Don't know much about perl, though...

I only found one question similar to mine but doesn't show any better solution, anyway, [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747309/match-any-substring-from-the-beginning-of-a-word).

Comment: What programming language? Probably easier to just do a string comparison than a regex.  Pseudocode: `substring(word, 0, length(partial_word)) == partial_word`

Comment: This classic problem is best solved by reversing the string and the pattern. Using Perl syntax for interpolating a variable into a pattern, that’s `"HORIZONTAL" =~ /^$word/i`, which will match "h", "ho", "hor", etc, but not "horripilate" and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify it with an `OR` expression:

```
/^(w|wo|wor|word)$/
```

or *reverse* the test by making a regex from the input text (in pseudo code):

```
"word" matches /input + ".*"/
```

Comment: +1 for reversing the test. That is clever. Unfortunately it makes it difficult to trawl through a large file looking for words so it is far less useful than a normal regex.

Comment: +1V for reversing the test. I was actually hoping for some recursive syntax available from regex themselves but the reversing concept is really worth having when dealing with cases like this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What if you did it a different way?  For example (I'm not familiar with ruby, so I'll use python):

```
s = "hor"

if "horizontal".startswith (s):
    h = True
if "vertical".startswith (s):
    v = True
```

Or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

Although ugly and harder to read, I would create a function to create the regex for each word. If it were PHP, for example, I would formulize it like the following:

```
function rx_from_word($word='',$escapeNeeded=true) {
    $rx = ''; $i = strlen($word);
    while (--$i > -1) {
        if ($escapeNeeded && strpos('|/{}[]().*\\+^$',$word{$i}) !== false) $char = '\\'.$word{$i};
        // I'm not sure if I missed any special character above.
        else $char = $word{$i};
        if ($i > 0) $rx = '(' . $char . $rx . ')?';
        else $rx = $char . $rx;
    }
    return $rx;
}

function rx_from_words($words=array(),$matchFull=false) {
    $rx = $matchFull ? '^' : '';
    foreach ($words as $word) $rx .= rx_from_word($word) . '|';
    return substr($rx,0,-1) . ($matchFull ? '$' : '');
}

$words = array('horizontal','vertical','$10');
$rx = rx_from_words($words,1);
echo "<pre>$rx</pre>";
```

which would output

> ^h(o(r(i(z(o(n(t(a(l)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?|v(e(r(t(i(c(a(l)?)?)?)?)?)?)?|\$(1(0)?)?$